# $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa}$ forces $\text{non}(\mathcal{M})\leq \kappa$ and $\text{cov}(\mathcal{M})\leq \kappa$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb{D}$ Hechler forcing.

Let be $\kappa$ an uncountable regular cardinal. Consider the finite support iteration $(\langle \mathbb{P} \rangle _{\alpha < \kappa}, \langle \dot{\mathbb{Q}} \rangle _{\alpha < \kappa})$  where $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a $\mathbb{P}_{\alpha}$-name for $\mathbb{D}$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$.

1. I want to show $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa}$ forces $\text{non}(\mathcal{M})\leq .\kappa$. To see $\text{non}(\mathcal{M})\leq \kappa$. Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ be of size than $\kappa$ in the extension, then there is $\alpha < \kappa$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is contained in $V^{\mathbb{D}_{\alpha}}$. As I conclude that $\mathcal{F} \notin \mathcal{M}$.?

$\textbf{Observation}$ Hechler forcing adds a Cohen reals.

Let $\mathbb{E}$ notion eventually different real forcing.

Let be $\kappa$ an uncountable regular cardinal. Consider the finite support iteration $(\langle \mathbb{P} \rangle _{\alpha < \kappa}, \langle \dot{\mathbb{Q}} \rangle _{\alpha < \kappa})$  where $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a $\mathbb{P}_{\alpha}$-name for $\mathbb{E}$ for all $\alpha < \kappa$.

2. A suggestion of how to show $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa}$ forces  $\text{cov}(\mathcal{M})\leq \kappa$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, the Cohen reals adjoined at each of the $\kappa$ steps (the reductions mod 2 of the Hechler reals) constitute a non-meager set in the extension.  The reason is that any code for a meager $F_\sigma$ set appears at some stage of the iteration strictly before $\kappa$, and the Cohen reals added after that step are outside that meager $F_\sigma$ set.

For Question 2, associate to each of the $\mathbb E$-generic reals $e_\alpha$ that were added in your iteration the meager set $M_\alpha=\{x:x\text{ is eventually different from }e_\alpha\}$. these $\kappa$ meager sets cover all the reals of the final extension, because every such real is added at some stage $\beta<\kappa$ and therefore belongs to $M_\alpha$ for all $\alpha>\beta$.

Comment: For Question 1, instead of using the Cohen reals obtained by reducing the Hechler reals, you could also use the Cohen reals that are added at limit stages of the iteration because you use finite supports.